# Result returns 0 on password hash validation

Tags: php, codeigniter, hmvc

I'm in the process of learning how to use the CI framework and am currently working on a user login form. Haven't created a user registration yet, so I'm manually adding credentials into the database. Since I'm testing everything locally, I decided to give crypt a try with no salt which is probably not the best method. I'm using form validation and a callback to check the form data against the information in the database.

here is a snippet from the users controller:

```
function password_check($password) {

$username = $this->input->post('username', TRUE);

$password = Modules::run('security/create_hash', $password);

$this->load->model('mdl_users');
$result = $this->mdl_users->password_check($username, $password);

if ($result == FALSE) {
    //$this->form_validation->set_message('password_check', 'Please login using the correct credentials!');
    //return FALSE;
    echo $password;
    echo '<br/><br/>';
    echo $result;
    echo '<br/><br/>';
}
    else {
        return TRUE;
    }
}
```

I echoed the password and the result for testing and password is showing as hashed.

Here is the password_check method:

```
function password_check($username, $password) {
    $table = $this->get_table();
    $this->db->where('username', $username);
    $this->db->where('password', $password);
    $query=$this->db->get($table);
    $num_rows = $query->num_rows();
    return $num_rows;
    if ($num_rows>0) {
        return TRUE;
    } else {
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

I'm sure the reason this isn't working is because the password in the DB is being treated as a literal string and not as hashed, but I'm not sure as to how I can compare it as a hash.

Comment: What `security/create_hash` does ?

Comment: That is a seperate security module that crypts the user input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this: get the user from the model and then check the saved value from the password with the hashed value from the user. If you would use md5 it would look a bit like this.

controller

```
$this->load->model('user_model');

public function login() {
   $name = $this->input->post('name');
   $password = $this->input->post('password');

   $user = $this->user_model->get_user_through_name($name);
   if($user['password'] == md5($password)) {
      //logged in
   } else {
      //wrong password
   }
}
```

model

```
public function get_user_through_name($name) {
    $query = $this->db->get_where('Users', array(
        'username' => $name
    ));
    return $query->row_array();
}
```

Comment: Of course, it was only meant as example for an easy way of authorizing a user.

Comment: In your example @MaxLangerak would the password need to be plaintext from the DB and then hashed to compare to the input data? I've stored one instance of the hash in the DB and am trying to compare the hashed input data to that, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: When the user originally inputs his password, you hash it in some way. This hashed value is what you store in the database. When logging in, you're hashing what the user fills in for his password (obviously, using the exact same method, so if you used md5 for the first password, you're going to use md5 for the second), then you compare this value to the value from the database. If these are the same, he/she filled in his password correctly, otherwise, he/she didn't.

Comment: Hmm... I understand that, and to expand on the issue, I'm using crypt to hash the input data. From the security module, prior to to hashing the input data, I used crypt to hash and echo the string I wanted to use as the password to be able to copy the hash and add it to the database. After which I then passed the variable on to use in the password check method. I'm still using crypt to hash the input data, and, in theory, if I use the same string that I used to generate the hash in the DB, it should work, right?

Comment: That's basically the idea of hashing, if you hash exactly the same thing, exactly the same thing comes out. So what you're saying should, in theory, work